# Xcode 9 + Cocoapods: 'No such module' even though I can use the module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have ran into a peculiar issue with `Xcode 9.2 (9C40b)` and `Cocoapods 1.3.1`. When I try to import the `GoogleSignIn` framework, Xcode complains:

[image: Xcode complaining]

But there are no other errors throughout the file regarding classes in `GoogleSignIn`, and when I CMD+Click on a class I can view its header (note the path at the top, which means that the framework definitely exists in my workspace):

[image: Header]

As a result, I can still reference types from classes involved in `GoogleSignIn` wherever I import it, but I am unable to build because Xcode thinks that the framework is missing.

Here's my Podfile. I have ran `pod update` and I am opening the `MyApp.xcworkspace` file inside of Xcode.

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'ActionsList', '~> 0.9.1'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Classroom'
  pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 3.0.3'
end
```

`GoogleSignIn` is the only framework where this issue arises -- I can use everything else flawlessly, and when I comment out all the code involved with `GoogleSignIn` (the `import` statement, all references, etc.) the app builds just fine. I should note that I have been able to successfully `import GoogleSignIn` in another project with Cocoapods

**How can I fix this issue and convince Xcode that the framework exists?**

Comment: Try importing it all into a bridging header.. then you won't have to type that import statement.. You'll just be able to use it.

Comment: @Brandon Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work either. I can `@import` other modules, like `Firebase` for example, into the bridging header, but when I try to import `GoogleSignIn` it still says 'Module not found'. Hmm...

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but have you explicitly tried to build? If the project is in a clean state, Xcode will not be able to find the module (because it hasn't been built yet), and thus will show this error. If you're still having problems, try deleting the contents of your DerivedData folder.

Comment: @Wilsonator5000; I don't mean to `@import` in the bridging header.. I meant to use `#import <BlahBlah/Foo.h>` for example. GoogleSigning may not support modules.

Answer (score 0):

- first of all make that pod: `pod 'GoogleSignIn'`
- In your app's project-Bridging-Header.h file, import the Google Sign-In SDK headers: `#import <Google/SignIn.h>`

  [GoogleSignInDOcs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) for more information

Comment: This still didn’t work... I also tried `Google/SignIn/SignIn.h` because I saw that file in my `Pods`, but still to no avail. I should note that I have been able to successfully `import GoogleSignIn` in another project with Cocoapods — I’ll add that to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be resolved executing the `cd project/directory; pod install` in the terminal to analyze, download and install your project dependencies.

My pod file contains:

```
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

And it's working.

Good Luck!